# Explicit Deselect in Sublime Text 2's Multiselect

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2

In Sublime Text 2, you can multiselect the next occurrence of a word with <kbd>Command+D</kbd> (on Macs, <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> on Windows). Is there a way to explicitly deselect an occurrence of a word?

Note: I know you can use <kbd>Command+K</kbd>, <kbd>Command+D</kbd> to skip an occurrence of a multiselect. The problem is that this command automatically still highlights the next occurrence of the word. I'm looking for a shortcut that simply deselects the last selection.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To deselect the last occurrence selected with <kbd>⌘ + D</kbd> try using:

On Mac: <kbd>⌘ + U</kbd>

On Windows: <kbd>Control + U</kbd>

*Update: Confirmed this works on Sublime v3 & v4+*

Comment: This does not answer the question of de-selecting ANY occurrence, but only addresses the last occurrence.  You cannot select the one after without re-selecting the one you just de-selected.  Fairly useless.

Comment: @MikeHall A) Works for me. B) Maybe you can create an SO answer about how to deselect the nth occurrence since you find that more useful for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following keyboard shortcut:

<kbd>Ctrl+u</kbd>

...or you can go the `Edit -> Undo Selection -> Soft Undo`

Answer (score 2):

On Mac you can deselect any occurrence by using <kbd>cmd+alt+shift</kbd>+<kbd>left mouse button</kbd>

I have not found the similar shortcut for Windows yet.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux and Windows, using the mouse:

- To remove a selection from the multiple selection: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RIGHT Mouse Button</kbd>
- To add a new selection to the multiple selection: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>RIGHT Mouse Button</kbd>
- To add a new cursor to multiple selection: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LEFT Mouse Button</kbd>

You may drag the mouse over what you need to deselect.

If you drag in the middle of a longer selection, you may end up with two new fragments of it selected that are separated by the area that you dragged the mouse over. Thus, sometimes by removing a selection you may create two new ones before and after.

Works in Sublime Text 3 as well.